# Debug Oracle DB Performance Issues

Tags: linux, oracle11g

The Oracle database is running slow,i have been trying to find the bottleneck.I checked the AWR for top 5 events,but didn't get consistent wait event to know the issue.

I noticed log file switch (private strand flush incomplete) wait event some times, so i altered the "_in_memory_undo" parameter to FALSE as per Oracle Support.

I still see no improvement.And i also noticed the CPU load is around 45-50% on server,but not able see which causing the issue.This is the only instance running on server.I have been monitoring through vmstat,iostat,top,sar commands,i see the load average is high compared to our better working environment. and also load is relying on swap memory.

Not sure increasing the RAM will solve the issue.Please suggest how i can proceed here?Let me know,if any information required to suggest here
Version:11.2.0.3.0 on CentOS(Linux)x86_64

Here is the top command output

```
top - 13:16:03 up 312 days,  3:55,  5 users,  load average: 41.31, 41.86, 42.04
Tasks: 333 total,   2 running, 331 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 25.1%us,  0.2%sy,  0.0%ni,  0.0%id, 74.7%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  24608556k total, 24419868k used,   188688k free,     7712k buffers
Swap: 18874360k total, 14735196k used,  4139164k free,  3111048k cached



PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
23414 oracle    20   0 18.3g 492m  44m R 98.8  2.0 179:33.16 oracle
   58 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  4.0  0.0   1456:15 kswapd0
19146 oracle    20   0  216m 4548 2088 S  0.7  0.0 582:28.76 tnslsnr
24230 oracle    20   0 18.3g 1.2g 808m D  0.7  5.2   0:39.01 oracle
    1 root      20   0 19404  516  296 S  0.3  0.0  85:40.07 init
 5374 oracle    20   0 17.9g 7100 6236 S  0.3  0.0   2:16.30 oracle
27673 oracle    20   0 15220 1452  956 R  0.3  0.0   0:02.11 top
```

Comment: More information on what "slow" means to you would be helpful. Are all queries slow or only certain ones? What exactly have you observed that is slow?

Comment: In my experience, when log file switch is biting you, you either do not have big enough redo logs, you don't have enough redo logs, or both.  Or, your redo logs are on a really slow disk subsystem. Or, you don't have enough `dbwriter` processes.  However, you will need to do more analysis to determine which part, if any, of this prescription fits your malaise.  I usually turn on the Diagnostic Pack in Enterprise Manager dbconsole and use it for quick collection of performance problems with SQL... but you will have had to license it to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your replies.Doug@The database is slow for all queries.Even select * from dual sometimes take 3-5 secs to give result.John@We dont have issues with sqls,as they are running fine in other environments.We recently increased the redo log size to reduce the log switches.Can you please let me know how i can confirm the slow disk is the issue here.